# Making struct fiels const in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, constants

given a struct:

```
struct not_const {
  int   a;
  char *b;
} nc;
```

Does it work to cast it into a const version of `not_const`?:

```
struct const_version {
  const int   a;
  const char *b;
};
struct const_version *c = (struct const_version *)&nc;
```

Could there be any padding problem?
I heard about transparent union but I think they are only used for function parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have `const` members you need `const` initializers.

Comment: the const version of `char *b` is `char * const b`, not `const char *`. The pointer should be const, not the `char` where it points to.

Comment: Why would you want to have such const struct? Why not simply use a `const not_const`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think that constness has some concerns about alignment. On binary level these types are compatible. You can go this way if you wish(this is how a lot of stuff written in C works - lots of network code, sockaddr_in/sockaddr_in6 - you can check header files if you wish). But as other folks stated it is better to have nc const * your variable/argument and it will eventually free you of strict referencing rule violation.

Answer (score 2):

The types are not the same and they are not compatible. The code violates strict-aliasing.

A compiler could put different amount of padding in between the struct members.

If you want to get a const members use the original struct definition and use a pointer to const:

```
const struct not_const* c = ( const struct not_const* )&nc;
```

This line will cause a compiler error as it should:

```
c->a = 123;
```

Comment: `const char *b;` does violate strict-aliasing rule, but what if `struct const_version` has `char * const b;`?

Comment: @sunqingyao Even if the struct definitions are identical and have the same padding,  they are not compatible if they don't have the same tag.

Comment: That's why I put a `char *`, but isn't there a way to ensure the "unmatibility" of all fields of a struct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the other answer is that the data is still modifiable 
through other agencies.

```
const struct not_const* c = ( const struct not_const* )&nc;
nc->a=some_other_value; // will still change the data.
```

One solution is to allocate some memory for `c` and copy `nc` it to it.

```
non_const obj1;
printf("Enter non_const int : ");
scanf("%d",&obj1.a);
obj1.b="SomeString"; 

/* Declare a const version */
const non_const *obj3;
/* Allocate the memory */
obj3=malloc(sizeof(obj1);
/* Copy the first object */
memcpy(obj3,&obj1,sizeof(obj1)); 
/* You may see a warning: passing argument 1
 * of ‘memcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type 
 * which can be neglected if i am not mistaken
 */
```

Comment: In fact, for a small school project I am developping a plugin system and I wan't the plugins to be able to read informations, but not writing, from the main program but those informations can change at any time.

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto : Then the other answer already met your need then